# too many arguments for public constructor `constructerName` defined in com.example.`constructerName` Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

in my MainViewModel class, I have 1 constructed. when I call this in my MainActivity.kt

```
private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by lazy {   
    MainViewModel((application as MainApplication).repository)
}
```

I am getting an error

> Too many arguments for public constructor MainViewModel() defined in com.example.MainViewModel

and if I call something from MainViewModel like this

```
        mainViewModel.subscribedToSleepDataLiveData.observe(this) { newSubscribedToSleepData ->
        if (subscribedToSleepData != newSubscribedToSleepData) {
            subscribedToSleepData = newSubscribedToSleepData
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error

> Unresolved reference: subscribedToSleepDataLiveData

Q. How to solve `Too many arguments for public constructor MainViewModel() defined in com. example.MainViewModel`

> MainViewModel.kt

```
package com.example

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.asLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.data.SleepRepository
import com.example.data.db.SleepClassifyEventEntity
import com.example.data.db.SleepSegmentEventEntity
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainViewModel {

    class MainViewModel(private val repository: SleepRepository) : ViewModel() {

         val subscribedToSleepDataLiveData = repository.subscribedToSleepDataFlow.asLiveData()

        fun updateSubscribedToSleepData(subscribed: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.updateSubscribedToSleepData(subscribed)
        }

        val allSleepSegments: LiveData<List<SleepSegmentEventEntity>> =
                repository.allSleepSegmentEvents.asLiveData()

        val allSleepClassifyEventEntities: LiveData<List<SleepClassifyEventEntity>> =
                repository.allSleepClassifyEvents.asLiveData()
    }

    class MainViewModelFactory(private val repository: SleepRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return MainViewModel(repository) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: error is - Too many arguments for public constructor MainViewModel() defined in **com.example.MainViewModel**

but all files are situated at :- **com.example.sleepAndroid**

and my package name is also: - **com.example**

If you find this question unusable, please do not devote this question as I am a super beginner in Kotlin.and I am trying to understand this code.

Q2. what is mean by `application as MainApplication`

Comment: Can you include the source code for your MainViewModel? It seems highly likely that it doesn't have any constructor parameters.

Comment: @  mabako  by mistake, I added code of a different class. now I added the right code. see again

Comment: Why do you have a class inside a another class i. e `MainViewModel` with same name ?

Comment: No it isn't, @ADM is correct, you've created an inner class `MainViewModel.MainViewModel`. You can take a look at how to declare Kotlin constructors here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class `MainViewModel` and that class inside has another `MainViewModel`. What you are trying to do is accessing the inner class.

```
MainViewModel.MainViewModel
```

The instantiation would be

```
private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel.MainViewModel by lazy {   
    MainViewModel.MainViewModel((application as MainApplication).repository)
}
```

Please keep in mind that Kotlin does allow you to have more than one class in a file. For that just delete the outer `class MainViewModel {` and the closing bracket at the end `}`, you will end up with one file having 2 classes inside `MainViewModel` and `MainViewModelFactory`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you answer this Question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514214/cannot-find-symbol-public-abstract-sleepclassifyeventdao-sleepclassifyeventdao